# Get input from from for php cURL

Tags: php, laravel-livewire, php-curl, sms-gateway

I am trying to send an sms using onfo. My problem is that I new to php cURL and im not able to give the correct recipient number from my form. I need to send the waybill number and destination to the recipient. See my code below.

I am using laravel livewire.

Below is the code in the parcel.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Man;
use App\Models\Percel;
use App\Models\Vehicle;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class PercelComponent extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $sender_name;
    public $sender_id_number;
    public $sender_phone_number;
    public $recipient_name;
    public $recipient_phone_number;
    public $recipient_location;
    public $parcel_name;
    public $parcel_quantity;
    public $parcel_value;
    public $parcel_destination;
    public $fee_charged;
    public $payment_method;
    public $vehicle_id;
    public $parcel_status;
    public $dispatch_date;
    public $user_id;
    public $parcel_description;
    public $waybill;

    public function updated($fields)
    {
        $this->validateOnly($fields, [
            'sender_name' => 'required',
            'sender_id_number' => 'required',
            'sender_phone_number' => 'required',
            'recipient_name' => 'required',
            'recipient_phone_number' => 'required',
            'recipient_location' => 'required',
            'parcel_name' => 'required',
            'parcel_quantity' => 'required',
            'parcel_value' => 'required',
            'parcel_destination' => 'required',
            'fee_charged' => 'required',
            'parcel_status' => 'required',
            'payment_method' => 'required',
            'vehicle_id' => 'required',
            'dispatch_date' => 'required',

        ]);
    }
    public function newPercel(){
        $this->validate([
            'sender_name' => 'required',
            'sender_id_number' => 'required',
            'sender_phone_number' => 'required',
            'recipient_name' => 'required',
            'recipient_phone_number' => 'required',
            'recipient_location' => 'required',
            'parcel_name' => 'required',
            'parcel_quantity' => 'required',
            'parcel_value' => 'required',
            'parcel_destination' => 'required',
            'fee_charged' => 'required',
            'parcel_status' => 'required',
            'payment_method' => 'required',
            'vehicle_id' => 'required',
            'dispatch_date' => 'required',
        ]);
        $parcel = new Percel();
        $parcel->sender_name = $this->sender_name;
        $parcel->sender_id_number = $this->sender_id_number;
        $parcel->sender_phone_number = $this->sender_phone_number;
        $parcel->recipient_name = $this->recipient_name;
        $parcel->recipient_phone_number = $this->recipient_phone_number;
        $parcel->recipient_location = $this->recipient_location;
        $parcel->parcel_name = $this->parcel_name;
        $parcel->parcel_quantity = $this->parcel_quantity;
        $parcel->parcel_value = $this->parcel_value;
        $parcel->parcel_destination = $this->parcel_destination;
        $parcel->fee_charged = $this->fee_charged;
        $parcel->payment_method = $this->payment_method;
        $parcel->vehicle_id = $this->vehicle_id;
        $parcel->parcel_status = $this->parcel_status;
        $parcel->dispatch_date = $this->dispatch_date;
        $parcel->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $parcel->parcel_description = $this->parcel_description;
        $parcel->waybill = random_int(1000000,9999999);
        $parcel->save();
        $this->reset();
        $this->sendMessage();
        session()->flash('message', 'Parcel created successfully and the recipient has been notified via sms. View history to print receipt for packaging. Thank You.');
    }



    public function sendMessage()
    {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.onfonmedia.co.ke/v1/sms/SendBulkSMS',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{
            "SenderId": "xxxx",
            "MessageParameters": [
                {
                    "Number": "2547xxxxx541",
                    "Text": "Hello. Your parcel of", waybill # $parcel->waybill "will be delivered within 24hrs to $parcel->parcel_destination.Thank You."
                }
            ],
            "ApiKey": "xxxx",
            "ClientId": "xxxx"
        }
        ',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'AccessKey: xxx',
                'Cookie: xx'
            ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        echo $response;
        return redirect()->to('/manager/percels');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $parcels = Percel::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->paginate(5);
        $sales = Percel::groupBy('user_id')->selectRaw('sum(fee_charged) as sum, user_id')->get();
        $cars = Vehicle::orderBy('registration_number', 'ASC')->get();
        return view('livewire.man.percel-component',['parcels'=> $parcels,'cars'=>$cars,'sales'=>$sales])->layout('layouts.admin');
    }}
```

Please help me how I can give the phone number to receive the message to be the $recipient_phone_number, the $waybill and $parcel_destination to appear in the message.

Comment: What does _"im not able to give the correct recipient number from my form"_ mean? Please be more specific. Where exactly are you stuck? What should the data look like and what does it actually look like? Do you get any errors? If so, where and what are those errors?

Comment: I would also recommend against manually building your JSON like that. It's much better to create an array with the correct format and use `json_encode()` to convert it into json. That will take care of any escaping that might be needed and removes the risk of typos in the format etc.

Comment: Under the MessageParameters, I want the 'Number' to be the recipient_phone_number. For 'Text', I need it to contain the waybill number and parcel destination. That is where I am exactly stuck

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$data = json_decode($response, true);
```

This way you are able to create an array and access via indeces

Comment: Under the MessageParameters, I want the 'Number' to be the recipient_phone_number. For 'Text', I need it to contain the waybill number and parcel destination. That is where I am exactly stuck

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your variables are not being returned correctly in your sendMessage() function put a dd($parcel) and ensure you are getting your variables first. second I would place a public $parcel at the start with your other public vars.

Comment: Tried it, it showed no error and message was not sent. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Idea is not for it to show an error message. Idea is for that to output the Variables of $parcel. If you have no values that means something in your code is not being set right. I would say try using $this->parcel as well. I have a strong suspicion your issue is related to variables.